# Simple Prolog predicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, prolog, logic

Is there any battle-tested way of declaring some (simple) **prolog** predicates and assert some facts, in **javascript** client code?

The best I could find is http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeLogic/Prolog.toy/Ch/04.Techn1.shtml but looks like it's calling some server-side "toy" interpreter.

Comment: What is your application here?  JavaScript is not Prolog, in any way whatsoever, so it would probably help to get an answer if you'd describe **why** you want to declare Prolog predicates in JavaScript code.  (What does that even mean, for one thing?  What do you need those predicates to *do*?)

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [Prolog in Javascript](http://ioctl.org/logic/prolog-latest) or [Yeild Prolog](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/). Neither implement the WAM, but might be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about Prolog is that it has a nice backtracking and unification engine built in the language itself. Javascript (as most languages, BTW) doesn't have this, so there is no way to get Prolog-style functionality "for free".

What you can do, of course, is write an interpreter for your subset of Prolog (or get it as a library from somewhere) and pass your predicates to it, encoded as some nice JS data structure.

But then, why would you want this at all? Do you need only backtracking? Do you need complex unification? Perhaps just writing a recursive search function would suffice? You question doesn't give many details.

Comment: What I need is stating facts and have quite simple inferences, so it's a really neat subset of prolog indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Prolog, and I think the other answers give great advice, but this might be a good library for what you're doing.  It's REALLY small.

It does add logic to the Array prototype, and I could imagine refactoring it to make the syntax cleaner... but personally, I kind of like how succinct it is.

Code contains 2 examples.

http://tinlizzie.org/ometa/ometa-js-old/prolog-base.js